# HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long - Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, windows-server-2016, iis-10

Have a .net Framework v4 aspnet website installed on webserver. When I run the site from the server it runs fine in Chrome. When I try to access the url from my computer using Chrome it gives me the 400 error size of headers is too long.

If use FireFox on my computer it prompts me for credentials and then the app loads fine no issues, but chrome errors out right away (not sure why Firefox is prompting for credentials).

I have done some looking and found lots of links about cookies being the issue, but this site doesn't use any cookies and I have cleared the cache and still get the 400 error:

[image]

I have added the following to web.config to try and increase request size but didn’t seem to help:

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10737418" maxQueryString="32768"  />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
```

Here is the Request headers from chrome Dev tools:

[image: Request Header]

Comment: The response doesn't come from your web site, but from the IIS kernel-mode driver http.sys, note the `HTTPAPI/2.0` as the server identifier. Somethings wrong here, but it is hard to say what exactly. Try checking the http.sys logs at `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can refer to this link about the solution: [HTTP 400: Bad Request explained](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/http-400-bad-request-finding-the-causes/).